# WP Не записывает полностью результат запроса в таблицу БД

Tags: mysql, wordpress, json, apache

У меня проблема с обновлением данных в базе данных `WordPress`. Я получаю запрос на выборку, который дает мне 2,4МБ информации, но когда я пытаюсь вставить его в пользовательскую таблицу по функции:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_updateDB', 'updateDataBase' );
function updateDataBase(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'sports_viewer';
    $wpdb->update(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'json' => $_POST['text'],
            'object_last_modified' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
        ),
         array('id' => 1),
         array('%s'),
    );
    wp_die();
}
```

Он передает только 16Кб информации, каждый раз. (В консоли браузера вижу Content-Length: 2254247) Я не могу найти, как это исправить. Посоветуйте, может это в самом сервере проблемы или где ?
*ячейка `json` имеет тип – `MEDIUMTEXT`
Apache крутиться MySQL / MariaDB - 10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В процессе дебагинга и тестирования было выяснено, что проблема в самом браузере.

Ни `Сhrome` ни `FF` не дают передать в базу больше ~450кБ полученых с `AJAX` запроса. => В браузер приходит предположим 2.4Мб но записывает только 450кБ... ломая `json` структуру.

Как решение было принято выполнять запись и запрос на получения большого json в php

```
$jsonFull = file_get_contents("https://api1.test.com");
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonFull,true);
```

А `ajax` только асинхронно дергать это выполнение на `php`

PS. Если кто-то столкнеться с той же проблемой и решит убедиться в моем ответе, то прервите выполнение отправки 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' какой-то дебаг функцией.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам стоит проверить настройки PHP. В первую очередь значение **post_max_size**

И вообще проверить что именно приходит в ваш скрипт. Т.е. Внутри скрипта сделать

```
$length = strlen($_POST['text']);
```

И куда-то вывести значение $length. Чтобы понимать где режутся данные - между клиентом и PHP скриптом или же при записи в базу.

Comment: `post_max_size 50M` А вот как вывести значения  $length Вне функции `updateDataBase()` что-то не пойму. Если просто в середине делать вызов, через ` var_dump(strlen($_POST['text']));`, то ни чего не отображает.